# How do I know which process or app currently accessing camera?

Tags: camera, linux, logging

How do I know which process or app currently accessing camera ?

android 5.1, nexus 5, shell access (no root)

Comment: I cannot possibly say whether [XPrivacy](http://xprivacy.eu/) is working fine on Lollipop, but in Android 4.x it had an option called "Restrict on Demand". The camera permissions are under "Media" section. All  you needed to do is apply this "Restrict on Demand"(only on Media) policy by default on all User/System/both apps and whenever some app will try to access this, XPrivacy will require your explicit discretion by popping up the details on screen. :-)

Comment: I think you should look on web for some advanced permissions manager for your said Lollipop version. If that manager has this auto restrict on demand like feature, then you have your answer right in front of you. That's as far as I can hint I assume. I should mention that mostly, these managers or likes of it requires *root* access.

Answer (score 0):

Try going into settings>privacy>privacy guard. It shows which apps has permission to camera, location, etc...
Also, when you're viewing all your apps in your setting, when u open them it usually shows which apps have which permissions.

Comment: I meant which app is currently accessing camera

Comment: Can't help with that then. Not sure. Within the same settings shows how many times it has been used also. So try there. At least that's how it is on my phone

Comment: I don't think it is exposed to user interface, any os level trick is what I am looking for

Comment: Also, the menu **Privacy > Privacy Guard** doesn't exist on AOSP Lollipop, perhaps you could mention the device model, Android version and if it's on custom ROM?